# Extract a column in pyspark dataframe using udfs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using below code snippets to extract a portion of a dataframe column .

```
df.withColumn("chargemonth",getBookedMonth1(df['chargedate']))

def getBookedMonth1(chargedate):
    booked_year=chargedate[0:3]
    booked_month=chargedate[5:7]
    return booked_year+"-"+booked_month
```

I have also  used  `getBookedMonth` for the same , but I am getting **`null value`** for the new column `chargemonth` in both cases.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring

def getBookedMonth(chargedate):
    booked_year=substring(chargedate, 1,4)
    booked_month=substring(chargedate,5, 6)
    return booked_year+"-"+booked_month
```

Is this correct way of extraction/substring of columns in pyspark ?

Answer (score 0):

Please DON'T use udf for this! UDFs are known for bad performance.

I would suggest you tu use [Spark builtin functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html) to manipulate dates. Here is an example:

```
# DF sample
data = [(1, "2019-12-05"), (2, "2019-12-06"), (3, "2019-12-07")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "chargedate"])

# format dates as 'yyyy-MM'
df.withColumn("chargemonth", date_format(to_date(col("chargedate")), "yyyy-MM")).show()

+---+----------+-----------+
| id|chargedate|chargemonth|
+---+----------+-----------+
|  1|2019-12-05|    2019-12|
|  2|2019-12-06|    2019-12|
|  3|2019-12-07|    2019-12|
+---+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a new function as Pyspark UDF.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
>>> data = [
...     {"chargedate":"2019-01-01"},
...     {"chargedate":"2019-02-01"},
...     {"chargedate":"2019-03-01"},
...     {"chargedate":"2019-04-01"}
... ]
>>>
>>> booked_month = udf(lambda a:"{0}-{1}".format(a[0:4], a[5:7]))
>>>
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
>>> df = df.withColumn("chargemonth",booked_month(df['chargedate'])).drop('chargedate')
>>> df.show()
+-----------+
|chargemonth|
+-----------+
|    2019-01|
|    2019-02|
|    2019-03|
|    2019-04|
+-----------+

>>>
```

withColumn is a right way to add a column, drop is used to drop a column.

Comment: Whoever has down voted my answer can you please explain why? My answer might not be the best one, but it's not a wrong answer.